# Understanding TikZ border anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a)[rectangle,draw,minimum size=3cm]{};
        \node [fill,circle] at (a.45){};

    \node(b)[below=1cm of a,rectangle,draw,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=3cm]{};
        \node [fill,circle] at (b.45){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the second node I'd expect the `b.45` border anchor to be at the north east corner of the shape, as is in the first node.

I think this depends on the shape of the node: if it isn't a square border anchors "move aorund".

Is there a way to predict where the `.45` border anchor will be located without going for trials and errors?

Comment: `b.north east` is another way to reference the right upper corner of any rectangle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you see, the second node is not a square but rectangle as you have added the option `,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=3cm` whereas `minimum size` fixes the same value for both height and width.

The following illustrates it further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a)[rectangle,draw,minimum size=3cm]{};
        \node [draw,fill,circle] at (a.45){};
        \coordinate (O) at (a.center);
        \draw(a.center) -- +(45:2cm)coordinate(A) (a.center) -- +(0:2cm)coordinate(B);
        \path pic[draw, angle radius=7mm,"45",angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle = B--O--A};

    \node(b)[draw,below=1cm of a,rectangle,draw,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=3cm]{};
        \node [fill,circle] at (b.45){};
  \draw(b.center) -- +(45:2cm) (b.center) -- +(0:2cm);
  \coordinate (OO) at (b.center);
        \draw(b.center) -- +(45:2cm)coordinate(AA) (b.center) -- +(0:2cm)coordinate(BB);
        \path pic[draw, angle radius=7mm,"45",angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle = BB--OO--AA};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another illustration:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node[draw=red,minimum size=2cm] at (0,0){};
  \node[draw=blue,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] at (0,0){};
    \foreach \x in {45,90,...,360}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\x:4cm)node[pos=1.1]{\x};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bottom line:

`b.45` is just at 45 degrees (fixed) from the positive x-axis. If you have a square centered at origin, then the north east lies at that position, otherwise not.

To find out where `b.45` lies, just draw a line with sufficient length:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node[draw=blue,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=3cm] (b) at (0,0){};
   \draw (b.center) -- (45:4cm)node[pos=1.1]{45};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The intersection of this line and the node border is the point you need.