# Need help regarding arrows in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows

I need an arrow diagram which would look somewhat like this:

[image]

The latex code that I've written for the same is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        
        \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm,text centered,text width=0.15\textwidth] (a) {Fuzzy regular open};
        \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm] at (6,6) (b) {Fuzzy open};
        \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm] at (12,0) (c) {Fuzzy $\gamma^*$-open};
        \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm,text centered,text width=0.15\textwidth] at (9,-6) (d) {Fuzzy semi $\delta$-open};
        \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm] at (3,-6) (e) {Fuzzy $\delta$-open};
        
        \draw[->] (a)--(b);
        %\draw[->] (b)--(a);
        \draw[<->] (b)--(c);
        \draw[<->] (c)--(d);
        \draw[->] (e)--(d);
        %\draw[->] (d)--(e);
        \draw[->] (e)--(a);
        %\draw[->] (a)--(e);
        \draw[<->] (a)--(c);
        \draw[->] (e)--(b);
        %\draw[->] (b)--(e);
        \draw[<->] (a)--(d);
        \draw[<->] (c)--(e);
        \draw[<->] (a)--(d);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

The nodes are okay, but I am struggling with the arrows. Also I want the arrow-heads to be a little bit bigger than they currently are. Kindly help me fix the arrows so that they are like the ones in the first picture.

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` in your preamble and then right after `\begin{tikzpicture}` add options for arrows between `[...]`, for instance `\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=3mm]}]` or `[>={Latex[length=2mm]}]` etc. This will define all arrows in your picture. for more details, see [`tikz manual`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) part III, chapter 16, p. 190

Comment: @Celdor Thank you sir for the reference.. It is really helpful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the final picture, but it includes all the elements you want, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Straight Barb[scale=3]},    % <--- added
    tick/.style={draw,minimum width=0pt,minimum height=3ex,inner sep=0pt,sloped},  % <--- added
]
    \centering
    
    \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm,text centered,text width=0.15\textwidth] (a) {Fuzzy regular open};
    \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm] at (6,6) (b) {Fuzzy open};
    \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm] at (12,0) (c) {Fuzzy $\gamma^*$-open};
    \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm,text centered,text width=0.15\textwidth] at (9,-6) (d) {Fuzzy semi $\delta$-open};
    \node[ellipse,draw,minimum size=2cm] at (3,-6) (e) {Fuzzy $\delta$-open};
    
    \draw[->] (a.80)--(b.200);  % <--- modified
    \draw[->] (b.230)-- node[pos=0.5,tick]{} (a.40);  % <--- modified
    \draw[<->] (b)--(c);
    \draw[<->] (c)--(d);
    \draw[->] (e)--(d);
    %\draw[->] (d)--(e);
    \draw[->] (e)--(a);
    %\draw[->] (a)--(e);
    \draw[<->] (a)--(c);
    \draw[->] (e)--(b);
    %\draw[->] (b)--(e);
    \draw[<->] (a)--(d);
    \draw[<->] (c)--(e);
    \draw[<->] (a)--(d);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to latex and do not know various things. So, I had to do a lot of internet digging before being able to write that piece of code on my own. In short, your answer has saved my soul for the day, and has also made me learn new things. Thank you so much sir...

Comment: Sir, will you please tell me what do 80 and 200 mean in `\draw[->] (a.80)--(b.200);` ? Are these some kind of coordinates?

Comment: Kind of ... Actually it is an angle. It is discussed with examples e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199822/263192

Answer (score 3):

Usinf Ti*k*Z libraries `arrows.meta` (for arrows heads), `quotes` (for marking lines) and `shapes.geometric` (for nodes positioning), common style for nodes' edges, where are two edges from nodes, their start and stop are defined by trials:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
       > = {Straight Barb[line width=0.6pt, angle=60:3pt 4]}, 
E/.style = {ellipse, draw, semithick,
            text width=5.5em, inner ysep=2pt, inner xsep=-3pt,
            align=center, font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize,
                                   anchor=center,sloped}
                        ]
\node (P)   [regular polygon,
             regular polygon sides=5,
             minimum size =66mm] {};
%
\node[E] (e1) at (P.corner 1) {Fuzzy\\ open};
\node[E] (e2) at (P.corner 2) {Fuzzy regular open};
\node[E] (e3) at (P.corner 3) {Fuzzy\\ $\delta$-open};
\node[E] (e4) at (P.corner 4) {Fuzzy semi $\delta$-open}; % d
\node[E] (e5) at (P.corner 5) {Fuzzy $\gamma^*$-open}; % c
%
\path[<->]   
        (e1) edge["$\mid$"] (e5)
        (e1.310) edge["$\mid$"] (e4)
        (e2) edge["$\mid$"] (e5)
        (e4) edge["$\mid$"] (e5);
\path[->]
        (e1.210) edge["$\mid$"] (e2.50)
        (e1.255) edge["$\mid$"] (e3.80)
        (e2.260) edge["$\mid$"] (e3.135)
        (e3.7)   edge (e4.173);
\path[<-]
        (e1.230) edge (e2.30)
        (e1.280) edge (e3.55)
        (e2.285) edge (e3.115)
        (e3.353) edge["$\mid$"] (e4.187);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So kind! Thank you so much sir for taking time to write this whole code.. I wish I could accept more than one answer!

Comment: @Usual_Learner, simple: accept this one, which on the best way solve your problem :-)

Comment: Umm.. That's a tough choice. Actually I have found both of the answers quite helpful. Two different approaches, and I have learnt new things from both of these. So, I am in no position to prefer one over the other. Since I accepted the other answer before seeing your answer, so I won't undo it now. Sorry sir... Don't mind. Your answer has its own beauty:)

Comment: @Usual_Learner, you prefer accepted answer. You not need to judgment to me your selection. It is all up to you. BTW, it is not good to rush by choosing the first answer obtained. It may happen that will come more answers with even better solutions ... But as I already said, all is up to you.

Comment: Noted sir. Will keep it in mind in future.