# TikZ and CircuiTikZ Graph Discrepancies and Proposed Solutions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circuitikz

Here is what I have right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{positionarrow/.style n args={2}{
        postaction = decorate,
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position #1 with {\arrow{#2}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{circuitikz}
                \draw [blue](0,5) circle[radius=1.5 pt];
                \draw[blue, positionarrow={0.5}{Stealth[inset=0pt]}](0,5) to (3,5);
                \draw [blue](3,5) circle[radius=1.5 pt];
                \draw(0,4) to[short, i>^=$\hphantom{a}$, o-o](3,4);
                \draw [blue](0,3) circle[radius=1.5 pt];
                \draw[blue, positionarrow={0.5}{Stealth[inset=0pt]}](0,3) to (3,3);
                \draw [blue](3,3) circle[radius=1.5 pt];
                \draw(0,3) to[short, i>^=$\hphantom{a}$, o-o](3,3);
            \end{circuitikz}
        \end{center}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I seemed to manage to get the circle radius to match that for `ocirc` (as shown in the bottom figure, the black `ocirc` with its default radius perfectly "covers up" the blue). Let me know if there's a better way of doing so.

From there, I would like to get some desired outputs:

1. I would like to have the line in `tikz` code to start from the edge of the circle and end at the other edge of the circle, like how the wires in `circuitikz` start and end from the `ocirc` terminals, instead of starting and ending *inside* the circles.
2. I realized that the arrow shape in `tikz` is not exactly the same as that in `circuitikz` (in reality, from my understanding, it is `flowarrow` that is defined as a node, not a specific arrow shape). Is there a way to get a `tikz` arrow shape that looks the same as that in `circuitikz`? If not, that's fine.
3. I realized the arrow in `tikz` that is positioned half-way (0.5) is not necessarily half-way as is the arrow for `circuitikz`. Is there a way for one to get the arrow in `tikz` to match up the position of that in `circuitikz`?

This is a follow up from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702226/graph-not-displaying-correctly), as I want to utilize curved lines (or directional edges in the graph, in other words) in addition with features from `circuitikz`, which does not use curved lines for wires.

Comment: Arrowheads are placed relative to the tip.  Diodes are centered.  Instead of an arrowhed, try adding a triangular node.

Comment: Hi John, interesting, so the tip is placed 50% halfway, not the arrow's center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible mixed solution (see also [my answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702275/38080)). Basically:

1. for the circles, use the shape provided by `circuitikz` (`ocirc`), which has the correct border anchors.
2. If you use it and use the *node name* instead of the coordinate, the lines will start from the correct borders.
3. Arrows are not really arrows in `circuitikz`; they are the `currarrow` shape (see section 4.11 in the current manual). So you need to use the trick shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702275/38080) and add a bit of tweaking on the position if you really want the same position.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
% get the circuitikz arrow size, define a tip https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549354/38080
\makeatletter
    \newdimen\ctikzAL\newdimen\ctikzAW
    \pgfmathsetlength{\ctikzAL}{ 1.7 * \pgf@circ@Rlen / \ctikzvalof{current arrow scale} + 2*\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\ctikzAW}{ 1.6 * \pgf@circ@Rlen / \ctikzvalof{current arrow scale} + 2*\pgflinewidth}
    \tikzset{c>/.tip={Triangle[length=\the\ctikzAL, width=\the\ctikzAW]}}
\makeatother
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/38080
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  % circuitikz arrows are not arrows, they are shapes centered in the path.
  % the 0.525 simulates the same position, if needed; adjust it
  mark=at position 0.525 with {\arrow{c>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
            \begin{circuitikz}
                \draw [blue](0,5) node[ocirc](A){} (3, 5) node[ocirc](B){};
                \draw [blue, ->-](A) -- (B);
                \draw(0,4) to[short, i>^=$\hphantom{a}$, o-o](3,4);
                \draw [blue](0,3) node[ocirc](C){} (3,3) node[ocirc](D){};
                \draw [blue, ->-](C) to (D);
                \draw(0,3) to[short, i>^=$\hphantom{a}$, o-o](3,3);
            \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (+1). But I guess that one `center` environment is sufficient. It not need to be two nested in each other.

Comment: Oh, yes. You are (very) right. I did not notice it ;-). Edited out.

Comment: Hi Rmano, thank you for your explanation. Might if you elaborate more on borders and border anchors? Like, might if you depict what you mean by illustration via TikZ or CircuiTikZ?

Comment: The basic documentation is here: https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.11; you can also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199822/understanding-tikz-border-anchor .

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood you, then you looking for the the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}
\tikzset{decoration={markings,
                     mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Triangle}} ,
                    },
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]}, 
      postaction={decorate}]   (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[red]     (0,-0.2) -- (3,-0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]